# Although flag is already set - Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm getting the error context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag although I already have it set. Any suggestions?

```
public class DataCountService extends Service {
    String text = "USR;1";
    String ERROR = Constants.PREFS_NAME;
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    private long period;
    private long delay_interval;

    private Intent getIntent() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Logging Service Started");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, DataCountUtilities.class);

        startActivity(i);  
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (intent == null) {
            // Exit gracefully is service not started by intent
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Error: Null Intent");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this code is cropped, I can´t see all I need, but what I can  see is that You have to set this before calling startActivity(i);

```
    Intent i = new Intent(this, DataCountUtilities.class);         
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Although @Opiatefuchs's answer is probably what you are looking for (you should add the flag **before** starting the activity) you may face another issue:

If the activity can be instantiated multiple times (e.g. if the service is started multiple times), you must also add the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK` flag:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, DataCountUtilities.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```